# Created a numbered list with For Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, for-loop

You would think I would get this done in 10 seconds, but I've spent 1/2 hour and am getting nowhere..Here is what I have/want:

```
  <table>
     <% i=0 %>
     <% for name in @names%>
       <% i++ %>
       <tr>
  <td><%= "#{i}" %></td>
  <td><%= name.first %>"></td>
       </tr>
  </table>
```

Yes, all I want is a numbered list of names, like:

1. fred
2. wilma
   etc...

The error I get is:
`compile error
/blah/_names.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected ';'
;  i++ ; @output_buffer.concat "\n\t\t  <td>"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<table> 
   <% @names.each_with_index do |name, i| %>
      <tr> 
         <td><%= i %></td> 
         <td><%= name %></td> 
      </tr> 
   <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: There is an extra `>` before the second `</td>`.

Comment: Thanks, i knew there was more then one way of doing this.

Comment: Doesn't add the dots after the numbers (An ordered list will do this for you)

Answer (score 4):

You should try using an **Ordered List** instead of a **Table**

```
<ol> 
   <% @names.each do |name| %>
     <li><%= name %></li>  
   <% end %>
</ol>
```

Comment: Agree! Unless you need the number to be read or something, an ordered list is the semantic and best way to do a numbered list in html. This way, if you use javascript to remove items from the list, the list should still be ordered.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `i++` in Ruby. Try `i += 1` instead.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrggggggghhhhh! Someone shoot me, I could not figure out what was wrong! Doh! That got it working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
  <% i = 0 %>
  <% for name in @names %>
   <% i += 1 %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= i %></td>
     <td><%= name.first %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```